# Simple:Python asks for input twice

Tags: python, python-3.3

Here is my code:

```
def calculator(value1,value2):

    function=input("Function?")
    if function=="*":
     return value1*value2
    if function=="/":
     return value1/value2
    if function=="+":
     return value1+value2
    if function=="-":
     return value1-value2
a=float(input("value 1:"))
b=float(input("value 2:"))
calculator(a,b)
print(calculator(a,b))
```

Output on Python Shell

```
value 1:5
value 2:5
Function?/
Function?/
1.0
```

So im just wondering why it asks for input for function twice, not once. This is probably a stupid question but thanks for answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two lines are causing your problem:

```
calculator(a,b)
print(calculator(a,b))
```

You're calling `calculator` twice, so it's asking you for input twice.

To fix your code, just store the result of `calculator(a, b)` in a variable and then print it out:

```
result = calculator(a, b)
print(result)
```

Comment: @user1973796: N[o](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_D_Z-D2tzi14/S8TRIo4br3I/AAAAAAAACv4/Zh7_GcMlRKo/s400/ALOT.png) problem.

Comment: @Blender what is that image? :)

Comment: @JonClements An article on [alots](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com.au/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html)

Answer (score 2):

You're asking Python to `print(calculator(a,b))` - this means Python has to evaluate the function twice. If you want to only input once, store `calculator(a,b)` in a variable and print that variable.